# Duplicated SignInCookie cookie in IdentityServer3

Tags: cookies, identityserver3

We started noticing we have two SignInMessages with the exact same id when authenticating using IdentityServer 3.  Checking the code, I believe this happens because one gets created on method "CreateSignInRequest" when authenticating, and also here after identityServer3 calls "AuthenticateLocalAsync", if "IsPartialSignIn" is set to false, like in our case, then this line is executed "signInMessageCookie.Clear(signInMessageId);".  This clear method, actually does a Cookie.Append, this is (I believe) why we have two SignInCookies.

Has anyone seeing something like this?  If so, were you able to figure out how to make it 1.  It's not a big deal, but would prefer to keep the headers smaller.

Comment: Actually it will become a big deal, because when you add 2nd, 3rd, 4th client the header will become bigger and bigger and soon IIS will throw an exception for the header size. This will happen, of course, if you are using different cookie for every different client, but anyway - it is good to deal with this problem on an early stage.

Comment: Well that will happen only if you have a high SignInMessageThreshold set.  But this case of mine, is 2 cookies in the header for the very same user/client.